# Quando estou falando dos Celtas, posso falar "Kelta" ao invés de "Selta"?

Tags: pronúncia

Em Inglês, Japonês e acho que também em Espanhol, Celta é pronunciado como "Kelta" e não "Selta".
A pronúncia "Kelta" é correta em Português?

Comment: Isto pode ajudar a dar contexto para uma boa resposta: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Celtae